# Why is visual studio IIS express trying to run asp.net full framework app with ASPNetCore Module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a solution created in Visual Studio 2017, with full framework ASP.NET MVC targeting v4.6.1, and angular 1.x. But for some reason, when I F5 Run the solution, it attempts to run using IIS Express AspNetCore Module, which is causing it to lead to

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Looking in event logs shows this as well

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/WEBAPPLICATION1' with physical root 'C:\Git\Angular1Demos\AngularDemo\' failed to start process with commandline '%LAUNCHER_PATH% %LAUNCHER_ARGS%', ErrorCode = '0x80070002 : 0.

Why is the module getting in the way here?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error if you create a new asp.net mvc project?

Comment: Sounds like your folder structure fooled IIS Express and made it feel like an ASP.NET Core app was there. https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Comment: yeah something is going on there where IIS express feels it needs to kick in the module

Answer (score 0):

So strange. I was able to workaround the issue by creating a new solution file in Visual Studio 2015, referencing the same project as the solution that was created in VS 2017. This time it works. Sounds like an issue with VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the IISExpress to IIS by creating new IIS profile and change the Lunch to IIS. It resolved my problem.
[image]